# linq/lambda best approach to project anonymous type to strong type

Tags: .net, linq

I have looked all over google but couldn't find a proper solution to my problem. 
I have a join result with 2 different tables, which have total of 30+ fields. It's obvious i can manually type out every field as below:

```
dbcontext.table1s.join(dbcontext.table2s,x=>table1ID,y=>table2ID, (x,y)=> new someTempClass {field1=x.field1,field2=x......})
```

I found this link, which is what I am looking for. However, it seems to work fine if the anonymous type look like {x} or {y} but not {x,y.field1}
http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2012/2/18/aspnet-mvc-generic-filtering-based-on-expressions

I really only need one field from table2.

Comment: My mistake, I posted wrong link. This is the CORRECT link.

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use Entity Framework, so if you want to select specific columns from an entity and project them to an anonymous or a strong type you can use projection queries.

```
// first we create a new class to contain less fields
public class PostRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

// returns posts with only the Id and Title
var posts = context.Posts.Select(p => new PostRow
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Title = p.Title
}).ToList();
```

https://www.talksharp.com/entity-framework-projection-queries

Comment: The problem i have is I want everything from table1 (20+ fields) and one field from table2. i made a query to join both tables which resulted in `code`(x,y)=>new {x,y.field1}`code`. I wanted to see if there is a way to bind this anonymous object to a strongly typed object without specifying all the fields.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for something similar as:
`dbcontext.table1s.join(dbcontext.table2s,x=>table1ID,y=>table2ID, (x,y)=> new {x,y.field1}).Project().To<someTempClass>()`
this way i wouldn't have to manually type out every single field. As I said in the post, the link i provided is sort of what I was looking for. However, it doesn't work with anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous type containing both types.
Something like this:

```
var collection = dbcontext.table1s.join(
    dbcontext.table2s,
    x=>table1ID,
    y=>table2ID, 
    (x,y)=> new 
        {
            X = x,
            Y = y
        });
```

You can then access the fields through the anonymous type. For example:

```
collection[0].X.field1
collection[0].Y.field2
```

Comment: That's what I said in my post. I'm aware you can create anonymous type with both resultset. My question is how I can project that anonymous type to an object without typing out every single fields. Keep in mind that my object will contain field from both resultsets.

Comment: You don't have to type every field out with the approach I posted. Do you need it flattened into a single object? I'm not sure I'm seeing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I need to flattening the anonymous type into a single object.

Comment: Could you post some more details on WHY you want to do this? I don't think it will be possible with anonymous types. What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: simple - I want 20 fields from X and 1 field from Y. X and Y are 2 different tables. Upon join result (X,Y), I want to flattening out the result to a strong-typed object. It is obvious you can do so by MANUALLY typing out all the fields or alternatively, I can create a view with the join result of these 2 tables. I wanted to do this without typing out fields. I did post on my question a link which someone accomplish this. However, it didn't work with my scenario.